# How can define a new parameter in function and later use it?

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I get the error: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'request_symbol'" when running my code. Can somebody explain how can i define new parameter in def and then later use it?

```
def request_income_statement (symbol, api_key):
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=' + symbol + '&apikey=' + api_key
    r = requests.get(url)
    data_IS = r.json()
    request_symbol = data_IS.get('symbol')
    return request_symbol

request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)

print(request_symbol)
```

Comment: `result = request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)` and then `print result`.

Comment: Your code should not raise that error though? Are you sure your sample code is representative of the code that caused the error? This code should raise a `NameError`, not an `AttributeError` (which would be fixed by changing `request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)` to `request_symbol = request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)`)

Comment: Note to self: revisit this closure after coming to a decision about the canonical to use for questions of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly returning a value from your function, with the last line `return request_symbol`

But perhaps your confusion is that only the *value* is returned, not the variable, i.e. the name `request_symbol` does not exist outside the function.

When you call the function `request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)` ....that statement itself returns a value (the value returned from your function), but you are currently not assigning the value to any var name.

Try this:

```py
def request_income_statement (symbol, api_key):
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=' + symbol + '&apikey=' + api_key
    r = requests.get(url)
    data_IS = r.json()
    request_symbol = data_IS.get('symbol')
    return request_symbol

myvar = request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)

print(myvar)
```

Do you see how the value moves between different var names now?

Of course you could also re-use the `request_symbol` name like:

```py
request_symbol = request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)

print(request_symbol)
```

But it's important to note that the name `request_symbol` outside of your function is a different variable from the one inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you need to assign the request_symbol to a variable outside of your function.

try something like:

```
result = request_income_statement(symbol, api_key)
print(result)
```

instead of your last two lines